# How to send emails in Google App Engine using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I am using a forgot password option in a form using Google App Engine in Java. The jsp program contains code shown below:

```
<input type="text" size=18 name="emailcheck">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

How can I validate the email address and send a reset email link to that validated email? Is the normal Java Mail API provided by Oracle, [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) will work with Google App Engine, or I need to write some specific code for Google App Engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Engine has its own [Java Mail API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview).

Comment: What if I want to use Java Mail library and not the App Engine one ?

Comment: This is a very old answer. Google now recommends integration with third-party providers. All of them offer very good free tiers, and integration can be done within a few hours (or less). If you want to use Java Mail, you can deploy it to a flexible runtime or a Compute Engine instance.

Answer (score 2):

I am sharing a link through which you can configure the email service in GAE.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail

You need javax.mail jar in you build path to configure it.

And make sure you use your admin email to send emails, with which you are deploying your application. And this will work only once deployed on Server.

> Code to Send Email

```
   import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
   import java.util.Properties;

   import javax.mail.Message;
   import javax.mail.MessagingException;
   import javax.mail.Session;
   import javax.mail.Transport;
   import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
   import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
   import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

   public class SendMail {  
     public void sendMail(String sendEmailFrom,String sendMailTo,String recipientName,String messageSubject,String messageText){
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop,null);
    try{    
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sendEmailFrom));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(sendMailTo, "Mr./Ms. "+recipientName));
        msg.setSubject(messageSubject);
        msg.setText(messageText);
        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("Successfull Delivery.");
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add javax.mail jar to a build path.

Comment: Well Sir, We need this Jar I have configured 4 of my running projects with this.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavamailjar.htm

Comment: I am using App Engine Mail API, and I do not have javax.mail in my build path. From documentation: "All of the JavaMail classes you need are included with the App Engine SDK". You can now remove this jar from all of your running projects :)

Comment: @ Ankur - Am i need to write any code after the line `String msgBody ='....'; ` am getting an error like this Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

Comment: @Sathya can you please paste the code, as per I think the code is working very fine which is provided in the tutorial.

Comment: @Andrei I will see if it is now included. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @AnkurJain i got solved the problem through think link http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/02/03/google-app-engine-sending-emails/ hope it helps for others. and the link you gave i tried the code but as i mention above the line gets error. i dint change or added any new code in that.

Comment: You are almost great @AnkurJain. You app engine are marvelous to bring the beginners out of issued.

Comment: @AnkurJain, is it possible to get the acknowledgement of the mail sent? I just want to know weather the mail is successfully received to the sent mail or failed? It may fail in some cases like the mail id that we are sending is wrong. In that case i want an acknowledgement.

Comment: @AnkurJain, can we use any email id as we wish in setFrom() ? We don't have to specify any password for that particular email id to send email from that mail id?

Comment: @Sreekanth the answer to your question is you can find in this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/bounce. Using this kind of code, you can check if the mail sent is bounced or sent properly. Earlier it was not supported by appengine.

Comment: @HariRam The answer to your question is no, because the email from which the mail needs to be sent must be having owner permission, which you can add from appengine console in the permissions tab on the left hand side.

Comment: If I run this code on a Flexible ENV of GAE it gaves me the following error message:

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to send\receive email, you could use access Google mail with IMAP. In this case, normal Java Mail API would be fine.

If you plan to have some special feature better to use [Google Java Mail API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/). It use the same interface as normal Jva Mail API. So you will need only to add google jar (do not forget to exclude oracle's mail jars).